# Refreshing an Object from within the Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure a way to refresh an object from within the object, though I'm not sure if it's possible.

What I mean by *refresh* is to replace the current object by calling a method instead of assignment.

This code will find each input element and store the element reference and each element's `name` and `value` properties in a separate array.

```
HTMLElement.prototype.getChildInputs = function() {
  let eles = [...this.querySelectorAll("input")];
  return {
    eles,
    fields: eles.map(ele => {
      return {
        name: ele.name,
        value: ele.value || ""
      }
    }),
    refresh: function() {
      return this.getChildInputs();
    }
  }
}
```

**Note** Keep in mind this is a minimal example

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.getChildInputs = function() {
  let eles = [...this.querySelectorAll("input")];
  return {
    eles,
    fields: eles.map(ele => {
      return {
        name: ele.name,
        value: ele.value || ""
      }
    }),
    refresh: function() {
      return this.getChildInputs();
    }
  }
}

let i = document.querySelector(".container").getChildInputs();
console.log(i);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="field">
    <label>first name</label>
    <input name="f_name" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>last name</label>
    <input name="l_name" />
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div class="field">
    <label>username</label>
    <input name="username" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>password</label><input name="password" type="password">
  </div>
</div>
```

In order to *refresh* the above object I have to use variable assignment, a.e.

```
i = i.refresh();
```

What I would like to do is be able to simply write

```
i.refresh();
```

And have the object rewrite itself. My initial attempt was the most obvious but it isn't allowed:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.getChildInputs = function() {
  ...
  return {
    ...,
    refresh: function() {
      this = this.getChildInputs();
    }
  }
}
```

Leading me to believe that it might be impossible, but I may be thinking about the problem incorrectly. Any help would be excellent.

Comment: By refresh, you mean a fresh query of children?

Comment: @Mrchief Correct. I would like it to requery the children of the HTMLElement and replace the `eles` and `fields` properties. I'm also aware that I could store a live list instead by using a variation of `document.getElementsBy`, but I don't want anything within the object to change unless I call the `refresh` method.

Comment: What is the end goal here? Are you creating a custom `HTMLElement`? If so why not define your class and extend `HTMLElement`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
HTMLElement.prototype.getChildInputs = function() {
  const parent = this;
  return {
    eles: [...parent.querySelectorAll("input")],
    get fields() {
      this.eles.map(ele => {
        return {
          name: ele.name,
          value: ele.value || ""
        }
      })
    },
    refresh() {
      this.eles = [...parent.querySelectorAll("input")]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: haha, oi vey. I feel like an idiot. I was massively overthinking. Explicitly updating the appropriate properties on refresh, and then pulling them from those properties for my other methods worked out perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: I was getting carried away too. :)